# WPF Combobox how to turn border red IF enabled and another field has a value >0?

Tags: wpf, combobox, triggers, converters

How can i set BorderBrush=Red if more than one condition applies?

This combobox is only enabled if the user has already entered a count of greater than 0, and it needs a selection before i can write the data (and i do not want a default value).  I already check in code to prompt the user to select a CountSource.  What i want is to have some sort of MultiConverter or Trigger or something that turns the combobox red as a visual cue to user to make a selection.  This converter/trigger/other needs to only turn it red when the user has entered a value of greater than zero in a previous field (SelectedClientDefaultCount) AND no count source has yet been selected (SelectedClientCountSource=null).

I tried:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveCountSources}" DisplayMemberPath="CountSourceDescription" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClientCountSource}"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedClientDefaultCount, Converter={StaticResource DefaultCountEnabledConverter}}">
                        <ComboBox.Style>
                            <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ComboBox.Style>
                    </ComboBox>
```

but it says BorderBrush cannot be found or accessed.  I also had no idea how to setup the second condition that checks if SelectedClientDefaultCount is not null or greater than zero.

I do not want to put this in a style outside of the combobox xaml, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set the `TargetType` of your ComboBox Style.
- Set the `RelativeSource` of the IsEnabled binding to `Self`.
- Use binding converters in the `SelectedClientCountSource` and `SelectedClientDefaultCount` bindings that return a boolean value.

---

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedClientCountSource,
                               Converter={StaticResource CountSourceConverter}}"
                               Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedClientDefaultCount,
                               Converter={StaticResource DefaultCountEnabledConverter}}"
                               Value="True"/>
               </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

Comment: perfect thanks!  i only needed two of the conditions, but this showed me the right format to get it done!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Style TargetType to "{x:Type ComboBox}"